# Wordpressでブログ記事を最新100件の中からランダムに取得したい

Tags: php, wordpress

wordpressのブログ記事を最新100件のブログ記事の中からランダムに3件取得するという条件に絞りたいのですが、なかなか実装できません。

```php
<?php $paged = (get_query_var(‘paged’)) ? get_query_var(‘paged’) : 1;
$args = array(
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => １００,
    'post_type' =>'blog',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
   <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
   //処理
   <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

今このような条件で100件絞っています。
そしてここから、ランダムに3件取得したいのですが可能でしょうか。
いろいろ調べてみたのですが、なかなかうまくいかず…。
ぜひよろしくお願いします！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**過去１００件の時、**
'paged'と同時指定した事がないので、動作するか判らないのですが。

パラメーター'**numberposts**'と'**order**'を以下の様に指定するとランダムな　記事１００件が得られると思います。
３件だけなら、`'numberposts' => 3,`にすると良いでしょう。

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 100,
    'post_type' =>'blog',
    'orderby' => 'rand'
);
```

追記、
**最新記事１００件からランダム３件**は　wordpressの get_posts関数と、shuffle使うと出来ますが
以下のサンプルになります。（the_postは使えないと思うので）

```
$argc = array('numberposts'=> 100,'order'=> 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'post_date','post_type' => 'blog');
$out = get_posts($argc);
shuffle($out);
for($i=0;$i < 3;$i++){
    $pt = $out[$i];
    $id           = $pt->ID;
    $post_date    = $pt->post_date;
    $post_title   = $pt->post_title;
    $post_title   = $pt->post_title;
    $post_content = $pt->post_content;
    //..etc
}
```